# JQuery Ajax Force Page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, refresh

I have here a form where that accepts user credentials. if the user has invalid user credentials the page will not load however if he or she has valid credentials I want the page to do full page refresh how would I achieve that?  I have tried adding.

```
window.location.href = window.location.href;
```

On the response html but it did not work, it seems like jquery is removing the script code?

here's the AJAX for form submission.

```
$('body').on('submit', '#sign-in', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url : url,
        type : "POST",
        data : data,
        //Do not cache the page
        cache : false,
        //success
        success : function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $('#loginModal').html($(data).find('#loginModal').html());
        }
    });
})
```

if the user has valid credentials the response  from the success would be this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
    window.location.href = window.location.href;

</script>
</head>
```

but the  page is not reloading.

Answer (score 5):

In the success function you can use the JavaScript way to reload :

```
location.reload();
```

A bit like this

```
$('body').on('submit', '#sign-in', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    var url = $(this).attr('action');
    $.ajax({
        //this is the php file that processes the data and send mail
        url : url,
        type : "POST",
        data : data,
        //Do not cache the page
        cache : false,
        //login success
        success : function(data) {
            //... your other code
            location.reload(); //reload the page on the success
        }
    });
})
```

That implies that your query thorws an error when the login fails so it doesn't go in your success function.

Comment: but what if the users input invalid the page will reload. only want the page to reload if the user has inserted a valid credentials

Comment: thats why I said in the success function

Comment: Even if the user inserts invalid credentials the success will still run. it returns different HTML data. so whether invalid or invalid the success will still run

Comment: Well there are two possibilities.
First : you throw an exception when the login fails. So that the Ajax request fallback to the "error" function.
Second : you return json or anything that can be parsed and you check in the `data`you received it the login was succesful. If it was, `location.reload()`else do what ever to tell that there was an error

Answer (score 1):

See if you can use this code in the **success** function

On receiving valid response (like 1)

```
$(document).attr('location').href='your location'
```

Comment: where would I insert that code? inside the success function? or in the html that has been responded?

Comment: In the success function after checking for the response from php
In php you can sene 1 on every successful login and 0 on every failed one.